# Using Layers (z-index) without leaving empty space

Tags: html, css

I want to put `<div>` above a flash object.

I managed to do so but the problem is that now I have an empty space where the div was.

I gave the div position relative and left & top values.

Is it possible to move objects with z-index without leaving a mark somwhere in the page(taking space and leave blank area)??

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

When you are using `positon:relative;` you are not taking the element out of the flow, you are only moving it from it's original position. You want to use `position:aboslute;` to take the element out of the flow.

When using absolute positioning, the coordinates are relative to the first parent element that is a layer. You might want to apply `position:relative;` (but no offset) to the parent element to make it a layer, so that the coordinates are relative to the parent, not the body.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a problem with your HTML/CSS, but rather something strange with Flash, where it always tries to be on-top.

[From this message](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/66057), the solution is to use pass the `wmode="transparent"` parameter to the flash file:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<EMBED src="swf.swf" quality=best bgcolor=#FFFFFF wmode="transparent" 
WIDTH="550" ...
```